# Python: vectorization over numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

`X` and `Y` are both 3d arrays with dimensions `(a,b,c)`. My goal is to do a dot product.

Consider that case where index `i` and `j` are scalar, and `(X[i,:,j].T).dot(Y[i,:,j])` would be simple and return a scalar.

However, if I try to do vectorization, `i` and `j` become 1d arrays, and `(X[i,:,j].T).dot(Y[i,:,j])` return a matrix but I am expecting a 1d array as result. How do I get around this problem ?

Comment: you can use np.einsum to calculate the product. if you can, add some random values with expected output

Comment: it would be nice if you could give us coherent code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive implementation using list comprehension:

```py
a,b,c = X.shape

r1 = [(X[i,:,j].T).dot(Y[i,:,j]) for i in range(a) for j in range(c)]
```

Implementation using [np.einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```py
r2 = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ik', X,Y).flatten()
```